# Arbitrary union/intersection in $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

It is well known that the definition of $\sigma$-algebra is concerned about countable operations.I want to find a  $\sigma$-algebra that is not closed under arbitrary union/intersection.

Comment: Take any $\sigma$-algebra containing all singletons, but not all subsets. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ for example.

Comment: @DanielFischer,thanks a lot, you could answer this question,so I can finish it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any σ-algebra containing all singletons, but not all subsets. The Borel σ-algebra on R for example.

Comment: (Wiki hammered as it is a literal copy of Daniel Fischer's comment)